# Joining mp3 files to form a stream

Tags: audio

I'm wondering if it's possible to, in real time, concatenate a series of mp3 files to form a live stream.

For example, in some directory I have file1.mp3, file2.mp3, file3.mp3 - each file is 1 minute in duration.

I want to load an mp3 stream which I could load in a web-browser or on a phone, etc which will join all these files together to form a 3 minute stream. However, say I'm 2 minutes into the stream and upload another file to that directory - file4.mp3 - that is also of 1 minute duration. I would want that to automatically be added to the end of my live stream, such that when file3.mp3 is finished file4.mp3 will start straight away.

I hope I explained myself well. I am just keen to know:

1) If there is a name for what I am trying to achieve?

2) Whether what I am doing is possible with current technologies.

Answer (score 1):

I think HTTP Live Streaming is what you're looking for. http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming